Is it possible to convert DM4 files to HDF5 files using Python?
I am currently looking for a way to extract data such as graphs and images from DM4 files and save them in HDF5 files with a hierarchical structure. In my search, I tried using Hyperspy, but it didn't work smoothly. The data was not saved in a hierarchical structure, and unknown values were stored. Only one or two datasets were created. I hope to be able to view the data from DM4 files directly in HDF5 files. In simple terms, I want to convert existing DM4 files into HDF5 files that users can view. Is this possible?
Here are the results obtained through Chargpt4
import hyperspy.api as hs
import h5py

def convert_dm4_to_hdf5(dm4_file, hdf5_file):
    signals = hs.load(dm4_file)
    

    with h5py.File(hdf5_file, 'w') as hfile:

        for i, signal in enumerate(signals):

            data_array = signal.data
            hfile.create_dataset(f'data_{i}', data=data_array)

    print("complete")


convert_dm4_to_hdf5('STEM SI.dm4', 'output.h5')


It seems that the actual data from the DM4 file was not properly converted to HDF5. While the DM4 file contains a hierarchical structure with groups and files, the resulting HDF5 file does not reflect this structure.

That image is consistent with the code - creating a number of datasets called data_1 etc.  Nothing in your code creates groups etc.  I have no idea what signals = hs.load(dm4_file) produces.

The raw data are converted to a hdf5 file. The code above is doing the following:

open the dm4 file into a hyperspy signal structure. Since there are four datasets in this dm4 file, hs.load returns 4 different hyperspy signals.
for each hyperspy signals, the raw data (here the attribute data of the hyperspy signals) is saved to h5py file as a h5py dataset.

To view the hdf5 file, you will need to different software that is able to read hdf5 dataset.
dm4 file can contain multidimentional dataset, it can be a spectrum, image, spectrum image, etc. If the dm4 only contain images, you could convert it to tif of jpg images:
import hyperspy.api as hs

signals = hs.load("dm4_file.dm4")

if not isinstance(signals, list):
   # when there is only dataset in the file, `hs.load` returns a signal
   # and not a list of signals
   signals = [signals]

for i, s in enumerate(signals):
   s.save(f"data{i}.jpg")

Then you can use any software that can read images to open the data.
